# How to increment div id value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have got a task to set the menu as selected. For that I use dynamic id.
So I want to increment it with respect to the selection

My code is

```
<div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top" id="menu"+ i>
    <span><a href="#" onclick="Home()">Home</a></span>
</div>
<div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top" id="menu"+ i>
    <span><a href="#" onclick="NewTransaction()">New Transaction</a></span>
</div>
<div class="menuHeader ui-corner-top" id="menu"+ i>
    <span><a href="#" onclick="Portfolio()">Portfolio</a></span>
</div>
```

javascript is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
             alert(document.URL);
             var list = $("#menu");
             for (var i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
                 list[i].innerHTML = i;
             }
             var str = document.URL.toLowerCase().indexOf("portfolio/index");
             alert(str);
             if (str >= 0) {
                 $('#menu').addClass("menuHeaderActive");
             }
         });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: ID's should be unique. I see you use "menu" as ID multiple times.

Comment: You can't perform operations in HTML. `id="menu"+ i` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Really what is the point of this way of doing it? Have you considered a simpler and cleaner solution?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var i=0;
$('.menuHeader').each(function(){
    i++;
    var newID='menu'+i;
    $(this).attr('id',newID);
    $(this).val(i);
});
```

Comment: Is there any change in html?

Comment: Yes, remove those Id attributes.. they are meaning less... you are giving ID's by jquery

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it with Jquery

```
val elementList = $(".menu");
for (var i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
    elementList[i].attr("id", "menu" + i);
}
```

Comment: is there any change in html?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a class name instead of an id, you will be able to reuse the code you have just added but in this way.

```
 var list = $(".menu");
```

One advice, don't do the highlighting of the item menu with javascript, do it server-side, and you can add the "activating" class directly in the HTML of the LI.

Comment: Altering `innerHTML` isn't what he's after. He's after generating a unique ID.

Comment: What I am saying is that it is not worth, not ideal, that is better to use or a class, or you give it a friendly id in the case that these options are not going to change. Sometimes just answering the question when you see a bigger mistake is worthless.

Comment: I know, but touching innerHTML wasn't of any benefit either way. If you look at his example, he's trying to indicate which menu item is the current page. (Which has nothing to do with incrementing the ID's number.)