# Auto increment numbers in div id javascript

Tags: javascript, auto-increment

can somebody please help me?
How to add auto increment number in div ID using javascript?
I have four divs and I'd like to have them automatically numbered (box1, box2, box3, box4) in the ID by javascript.

Here's my code

```
<div id="box" class="something"> </div>
<div id="box" class="something"> </div>
<div id="box" class="something"> </div>
<div id="box" class="something"> </div>

<script>
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
  for (var i = 0; i <= list.length; i++) {
   list[i].innerHTML = i;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: To start, don't use duplicate IDs.

Comment: @Csülök Pug , please, take a look [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11026258/html-and-javascript-auto-increment-number)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increment div id value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745193/how-to-increment-div-id-value)

Answer (score 1):

set id property

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].id = "box" + (i + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code: `<=` should be only `<` if you are starting from `0`!

One possible solution is to use the [node.setAttribute("attributeName", "attributeValue") method](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domattribute.shtml) in order to set / change the attribute (in this case the `id`) of an element:

```
<div id="box" class="something">A</div>
<div id="box" class="something">B</div>
<div id="box" class="something">C</div>
<div id="box" class="something">D</div>

<script>
  var list = document.getElementsByClassName("something");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
   list[i].setAttribute("id", "box" + i);
  }
</script>
```

The output is:

```
<div id="box0" class="something"></div>
<div id="box1" class="something"></div>
<div id="box2" class="something"></div>
<div id="box3" class="something"></div>
```

If it is alright to use JS libraries (for example jQuery), then the transformation could be written even more succinctly:

```
$(".something").each(function(index) {
    $(this).attr("id", this.id + index);
});
```

This code leads to the same output as above.

The commented jQuery code:

```
// find all elements with the class "something"
$(".something")
// call for each one of them 
    .each(
// the function with parameter = current index
    function(index) {
// take the current element
    $(this)
// and set the attribute id to the new value
    .attr("id", this.id + index);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you tell me if I need to add something to the head section. Because this code did not work for me when I inserted it into the html file.

Comment: The first part should work without additional code. The second part uses the [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/). You need to download the library locally and reference it from your computer/server or reference it directly from the web, for example from here [cdnjs.com](http://cdnjs.com/) like this: `<script src="<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" async=""></script>" type="text/javascript"></script>`. This code should be put in the header of the html page.