# Increment HTML ID Based On Class Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Using javascript or jquery, how can I increment the html ID for items which have the same html class.  For example, I have 3 elements with the class 'form_id'.  I would like for the id of each respective element to show as

1. form-0-id
2. form-1-id
3. form-2-id

I am trying this - but it is not working:

```
var list = $(".formset_id");  
var q = 0
for (var item in list) {
   var newID='form'+q+'-id';
   $(this).attr('id',newID);
   q++;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that `this` in your `for` loop is the window or document, not a form element

Comment: Duplicate of [Auto increment numbers in div id javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24845085/auto-increment-numbers-in-div-id-javascript)

Comment: I used what I used because your coding style seems to imply that you have to support legacy browsers, but I'd agree with @slappy and his final ES6 approach, which is cleaner and doesn't depend on unnecessary use of non-native APIs (jQuery).  I only disagree with his implying that `.forEach` is somehow an inferior approach.  It is neither less readable, nor less performant (actually forEach would make use of native-level optimizations in V8, whereas for-of+entries doesn't get those optimizations yet).

Comment: @user120242: I'm not sure how I implied that `.forEach` is inferior. Was it because my bottom solution used `for-of`? I didn't take the last step to post a `.forEach` solution at the bottom, because I was already using it as my main solution in the top demo. Mostly I was trying to walk the OP through a process of eliminating jQuery and shortening the code. Hope that clarifies my answer. My main bias is native code over large abstractions when possible.

Comment: They are all valid since OP didn't specify anything. And all unnecessary since they were already posted as answers on duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [each](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to iterate over the divs.

`.html()` call is just so that you can visibly see the results.  Remove it and replace it with your own code.  First parameter of each callback function is the index, second parameter is the value.

Note: There is probably a better solution to whatever it is you are trying to do.  Setting `id` like this is usually unnecessary and indicates a roundabout approach to whatever it is you are trying to achieve that is most likely unreliable.

```js
var list = $(".formset_id");  

list.each(function(q){
  var newID = 'form'+q+'-id';
   $(this).attr('id',newID);
   $(this).html(q);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
```

Detailed explanation for why your code doesn't work as-is, and why you shouldn't use for-in:
*(If you know what you are doing and have to support older browsers, it's a good poor man's object [key]:value iterator for older browsers)*
for-in loops iterate over all the *keys* of the object, not the values.  You shouldn't use for-in, because it will also iterate over the jQuery extended built-ins (like `attr`, `each`, `map`, `html` etc).  It also undermines browser optimizations and is not any cleaner to read.
You only needed it as a poor man's for-of in old legacy browsers.  For which you would have to add `.hasOwnProperty` to make sure it isn't a built-in method's key, and in the case of the jQuery object you have to also exclude `length` and `prevObject`, which are updated as properties to allow it to act Array-like and DOM-like.

```js
var list = $(".formset_id");  
for (var item in list) {
   var newID='form'+item+'-id';
   // skip over special jQuery built-ins unrelated to actual contained elements
   if(!list.hasOwnProperty(item) || item==='length' || item==='prevObject')
     continue;

   $(list[item]).attr('id',newID);
   $(list[item]).html(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
```

Comment: Why is the `.html()` here? Ah okay, I got it...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you haven't grasped some language basics, like how `this` works, and how the `for-in` loop works.

Here's a non-jQuery version that does what you want, without needing large external dependencies.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".formset_id")
  .forEach((el, i) => el.id = `form${i}-id`);
```

```css
.formset_id {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#form0-id {
  background: red;
}

#form1-id {
  background: green;
}

#form2-id {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
<div class="formset_id"></div>
```

---

However, to make your actual code work, it would be like this:

```
var list = $(".formset_id");  
var q = 0
for (var item in list) {
   var newID='form'+q+'-id';
   $(list[item]).attr('id',newID);
   q++;
}
```

---

Taking one step away from jQuery, you'd set the `.id` property of the element directly.

```
var list = $(".formset_id");  
var q = 0
for (var item in list) {
   var newID='form'+q+'-id';
   list[item].id = newID;
   q++;
}
```

---

And then the loop body can be done in one line.

```
var list = $(".formset_id");  
var q = 0
for (var item in list) {
   list[item].id = 'form' + q++ + '-id';
}
```

---

And a `for-of` loop on the `Object.entries` of the list would be nicer too, eliminating the `q` variable.

```
var list = $(".formset_id");  

for (var [i, item] of Object.entries(list)) {
   item.id = 'form' + i + '-id';
}
```

---

And using string interpolation is nice too.

```
var list = $(".formset_id");  

for (var [i, item] of Object.entries(list)) {
   item.id = `form${i}-id`;
}
```

---

And you can see that the only jQuery is the DOM selection, so why bother?

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll(".formset_id");  

for (var [i, item] of Object.entries(list)) {
   item.id = `form${i}-id`;
}
```

And now we're almost exactly the same as my demo at the top, except that we're using `for-of` instead of  `.forEach` iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`attr(attributeName, function)`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function) which will loop over the whole collection and also expose the index of each iteration

```js
$(".js-form").attr('id', i => `form-${i}-id`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<form action="/" class="js-form">Form 1</form>
<form action="/" class="js-form">Form 2</form>
<form action="/" class="js-form">Form 3</form>
<form action="/" class="js-form">Form 4</form>
<form action="/" class="js-form">Form 5</form>
```